# Shortcut for selection till next capital letter IntellIJ/ Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea

Say I have following two strings.

```
String s = "update_user_name";
String s = "updateUserName";
```

Currently I use **`CTRL + SHIFT + (Right/Left Arrow)`** to make whole world selection.

Is there a shortcut for selecting till next capital letter (in 2nd case). Or for different part of word?

I hope there is one shortcut that I don't know.

So that when I press that shortcut that select only **update** from these strings. Then on next press it select **update_user/ updateUser**.

**Please note** this shortcut is expected to work with method names/ strings/ or any text in code.

I hope you understood me.

Answer (score 12):

enable Use "CamelHumps" words in Settings | Editor | General | Smart Keys

Comment: Where do you put the caret? At the beginning of the word?

Comment: @Khemraj Old question, I know - but if you still want a double click to select the whole word, you can uncheck 'Editor -> General -> Honor "CamelHumps" words settings when selecting on double click'

Comment: In Rider 2023.1.2 this setting is in: Settings/Editor/General/Typing Assistance : (checkbox) Use CamelHumps

Answer (score 1):

I rather create a shortcut (in keymap) to jump to the capitalLetter.
Here is how you do it:

Steps:

1. open settins `(CTRL + ALT + S)`
2. search for `camelHump`
3. in keymap, for "Move Caret to the Next word With Selection"
4. set shortcut key as per your desire.
   e.g. i put shortcut as `ALT+SHIFT+rightArrow`, because it is similiar to `ALT+CTRL+rightArrow` (which is used to select whole word)